# Mapping data from text to List

Tags: java, mapping

Consider the following set of data

```
<Driver name,surname,licence id,age>

<Number of licences>

<licence name,id,penalty points>
```

Example:

```
John, Long, 1234567890, 21
2
Motorcycle licence, 12345, 0.0
Car Licence, 01234, 22, 3.0
Rose, Black, 0234567891, 30
4
Motorcycle licence, 12345, 0.0
Car Licence, 01234, 22, 1.0
Truck Licence, 23456, 1.0
Trailer Licence, 34567, 1.0
```

This would be my POJO's

```
class Driver {
  private String driverName;
  private String surname;
  private int licenceId;
  private int age;
  private List<Licence> licences;
}
class Licence {
  private String licenceName;
  private int licenceID;
  private Double penaltyPoints;
}
```

this is my List. I think I should have a list of lists.

List driverList = new ArrayList<>();

```
// this is the method I have to map the customer details to my customer
static void readData(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, InvalidPropertiesFormatException {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] split = s.nextLine().split(",");
      driverList.add(new Customer(split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3]));
    }
    s.close();
}
```

One solution would be to repeat the process, maybe make the readData more generic, to take a list to which I can add the Customer and call the method again to add the account.

I think there is a better solution? Maybe a list of lists?

Another solution would just to read the data from the file and try to manipulate it that way

```
///this is my method to read data from file and put it in a List, it is not efficient as it puts
    static void readData(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        while (s.hasNext()){
            String[] split = s.nextLine().split(",");
            driverList.add(Arrays.toString(split));
        }
        s.close();
    }
```

The problem here is that I can't access the index of driver list.

**Expected Result:**

```
[
[John, Long, 1234567890, 21, 2, Motorcycle licence, 12345, 0.0,Car Licence, 01234, 22, 3.0]
[Rose, Black, 0234567891, 30, 4, Motorcycle licence, 12345, 0.0, Car Licence, 01234, 22, 
1.0, Truck Licence, 23456, 1.0, Trailer Licence, 34567, 1.0]
]
```

Comment: Creating a lists of lists as a final result isn't really an option if you'd like to store values of different types in them. I guess you could create List<List<Object>> and then cast values to specific types from specific indices but I think this wouldn't be clean. I suggest creating a list of Drvier POJOs as shown in your question. Firstly however, I'd separate the lines from the file into a List<List<List<String>>> where the middle list (List<List<String>>) would be the driver and his or her licences - having that you can create your POJOS one by one.

Comment: thank you. it makes sense theoretically. List<List<List<Driver>>>. 
how to implement, not so sure.
As you can see the lines are not equal in attributes.

Comment: I was thinking about List<Driver> as the final result and List<List<List<String>>> as the middle form after processing the data from the file. To create the List<List<List<String>>> you could load all the lines from the file into a buffer (List<String>) and then determine which lines are drivers, numbers of licences and licences by checking their split length and the element's from the next index split length. So if an element's split length is 4 and the next element's is 1 - that means that it's a driver and the next n elements are licences.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my comments to your question, here's how you can create `List<List<List<String>>` where the first element is the driver and the rest are licences:

```
    List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./data"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<List<List<String>>> parsedData = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean creatingNewElement = false;
    Integer licenceCount = 0;
    List<List<String>> newElement = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
        String[] bufferLineSplit = buffer.get(i).split(", ");
        if (bufferLineSplit.length == 4 && !creatingNewElement) {
            String[] nextBufferLineSplit = buffer.get(i + 1).split(", ");
            if (nextBufferLineSplit.length == 1) {
                creatingNewElement = true;
                newElement = new ArrayList<>();
                newElement.add(Arrays.asList(bufferLineSplit));
                licenceCount = Integer.parseInt(buffer.get(i + 1));
            }
        } else if (bufferLineSplit.length == 1) {
            continue;
        } else if (creatingNewElement) {
            newElement.add(Arrays.asList(bufferLineSplit));
            licenceCount--;
            if (licenceCount == 0) {
                parsedData.add(newElement);
                newElement = null;
                creatingNewElement = false;
            }
        }
    }

    parsedData.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Based of that `List<List<List<String>>`, you can create POJOs as shown in your question.

Result:

```
[[John, Long, 1234567890, 21], [Motorcycle licence, 12345, 0.0], [Car                 
Licence, 01234, 22, 3.0]]
[[Rose, Black, 0234567891, 30], [Motorcycle licence, 12345, 0.0], [Car 
Licence, 01234, 22, 1.0], [Truck Licence, 23456, 1.0], [Trailer 
Licence, 34567, 1.0]]
```

Comment: I've tried your program. it doesn't return your result. maybe doing something wrong.

Comment: Is there something I miss from your code?

Comment: In my code I'm reading a file from the path "./data" with the example data from your question - did you replace that part with your file's path? If not, is there an error? What's the output you're getting?

Comment: I don't get any error. The terminal is just empty. no result.

Answer (score 0):

When picking apples in a garden one is dividing the apples as picked up or can pick apples and store em in a barrel for later sorting.

We have 2 solutions. Same with my algorithm/problem.

In this scenario the mapping can be done at the reading time.